# ¿Por qué lista.append(...) devuelve None?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo un ejercicio de funciones donde debo hacer esto:

*"Escriba una función que reciba como parametro un número entero y una lista, debe de adicionar a la lista el numero elevado al cubo y devolver la lista con el nuevo elemento."*

Estuve googleando y probando numerosas opciones, pero no me sale. Lo pensé así:

```
def funcion6(entero, lista):
    return lista.append(entero**3)

ejercicio_6 = funcion6(2, [1,2,3])
print(ejercicio_6)

>>>None
```

Pero como ven, me arroja "None".

Imagino que debe ser algo muy simple, pero estoy hace tiempo con esto y creo que pueden darme una mano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python te jugó una pequeña trampita en la que todos caemos:

```
lista.append(entero**3)
```

Esta expresión **no** retorna una lista actualizada, como uno creería; simplemente *modifica* la lista.

La solución es simple: luego de actualizar la lista, retornala en una instrucción separada:

```
def funcion6(entero, lista):
    lista.append(entero**3)
    return lista
```

Comment: De hecho, es muy común que los métodos *no devuelvan* el objeto principal. Por ejemplo en tKinter un error que se ve muchísimo es la gente *guardando* botones así: `boton1 = Button(root, text="Soy un botón").pack()`, lo cual casualmente **no devuelve un botón**! Hay que tener muchísimo cuidado con los *return type* de los métodos :)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ahora entiendo.
Estaré atento la próxima.

Saludos Candid!

Y gracias por el comentario Benito!